# Why does data give me null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, viewcontroller

I'm trying to pass a `NSDictionary`from a `TableViewController`to a `ViewController`. In my `TableViewController.m`. I have this code to navigate to the `ViewController`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *objectDict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Info: %@", objectDict);
    // Pass object to new page
    //UIViewController * vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    //[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    SeeInfoVC *controller = [[SeeInfoVC alloc] init];
    controller.data = objectDict;

    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SeeInfoVC"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In my `ViewController.h` I have:

```
@interface SeeCardVC : UIViewController
{
    NSDictionary *data;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSDictionary *data;


@end
```

And then I'm trying to log `data` in `ViewController.m`:

```
@implementation SeeCardVC
@synthesize data;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"Info: %@", data);

}
```

But it only gives me null :(
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what your code is doing here:

```
// Create new controller, assign objectDict to data property
SeeInfoVC *controller = [[SeeInfoVC alloc] init];
controller.data = objectDict;

//Get Storyboard name
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
//Get Storyboard (BTW, you can do this with self.storyboard)
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
//Instantiate NEW controller
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SeeInfoVC"];
//Present NEW controller
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You created a controller and assigned data to it, and then didn't use it anymore, instead you created a new one from the storyboard, you didn't add the data and presented it.

Basically, you created two, set data to one and presented the other one.

See the problem?

Comment: Yes I can see! But how should I do it then? Im kinda confused @EmilioPelaez

Comment: If i remove NSString, UIStoryboard and UIViewController, it logs the data, but the screen is black :)

Comment: I'm glad you found out the answer. Truth is I could've said "Change these lines for these other lines" but when possible I like to encourage people to learn instead of just flat out giving them the answer, this way you probably won't come back with the same question.